# How to trigger requests in asynchttpserver Nim

Tags: server, request, nim-lang

I don't know how to catch and make condition on request here, like i usually do in PHP:

```
if(isset($_GET['do']){$page = $_GET['do']}`
```

but i even do not understand how to the same here

```
import asynchttpserver, asyncdispatch

var server = newAsyncHttpServer()
proc cb(req: Request) {.async.} =
  await req.respond(Http200, "Hello World")

waitFor server.serve(Port(1337), cb)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use another library that builds this functionality. `asynchttpserver` offers the fundamentals, so it just exposes the raw data of the request in the `Request` data type.

Consider using [Jester](https://github.com/dom96/jester) (examples in readme) or another web framework.